# converting Image raw data to bitmapimage in windows universal app

Tags: win-universal-app

I am trying to implement a windows universal application. I am facing one issue for converting the image raw data(byte array) to the BitmapImage control. I don't know the type of the image raw data. I used the below code,

```
private async Task<BitmapImage> ByteArrayToBitmapImage(byte[] byteArray)
{
    var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

    var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    await stream.WriteAsync(byteArray.AsBuffer());
    stream.Seek(0);

    bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
    return bitmapImage;
}
```

Image is not displayed in window. When I debugging , found that  height & width of bitmapImage object is 0.

if anybody know the solution for this, please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally my issue solved , when I used the below code,

```
    var bmp = new WriteableBitmap(320, 240);
    using (var stream = bmp.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
    {
        stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        myImage.Source = bmp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same code and in works for me but I create BitmapImage and set its source on dispatcher's thread - maybe that's the key to your problem.

Comment: I tried it. but no hope.. .It seems that BitmapImage object pixelheight & pixelWidth properties are zero.

Comment: Here the image raw data doesn't contains the header data.. that is the issue.